# Will I get additional week when reach a milestone year like every one else if started with one extra week?

Tags: vacation

I was offered extra vacation week to be recognized my experience.  It says in my offer letter" **This level of vacation time will remain in effect until you are eligible for additional time off under our vacation policy**".  I assumed that I will accrue additiona vacation week just like every else.  Our policy says, "**Acrrual of additional week occurs at the begining of the milestone year**".  Employees will get 1 extra week starting year 5 and another week starting year 10.  My manager said that I will not acrrue extra week until yr 10.  Who is right, my manager or I? If he's right, my advantages will only be for the first 4 years.

Comment: It's whatever your company says it is. They offered it, they get to decide the terms.

Comment: That doesn't seem ambiguous to me, it says at the five year mark you lose your current "bonus extra week" and gain the same extra week as everyone else. Net result: no change.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a company's policy and not a general workplace question.

Answer (score 5):

Usually no, unless you negotiated that into your contract before you signed on.

Most often I have seen where a company will start an employee with 3 weeks of vacation and then they are not awarded another until they would normally be eligible for the 4th week.

It is pretty rare to get a company to commit to giving an extra week of vacation in addition to what is earned though Time of service.  I have seen contracts where time of service was calculated as though the employee had X number of years(usually 2, 5 or 7) in addition to their actual time of service.

This is something to talk about before you sign any agreement.  If you do sign a contract that says you get credit for 5 years of service, and they change their 3rd week of vacation award to 10 years you could lose that extra week of vacation.  I did work for a start up for just over a year.  The promise was 3 weeks at 3 years and everyone was hired on with 2 years credit toward that 3.  Then at just short of the companies year anniversary they moved it to 5 years as well as pushing off other benefits.  Needless to say this started a quick down hill slide as they started losing people, and the company was not around to issue a W2 for me the next year.

Comment: our vacation policy is everyone starts with 2 wks and will get 3 wks at the beginning of yr5 and 4wks at yr. 10.

Comment: our vacation policy is everyone starts with 2 wks and will get 3 wks at the beginning of yr5 and 4wks at yr. 10.  As I said, I was given 3 wks to start with and the first paragraph in bold is what it says in the offer letter. To my understanding, every one is eligible for addition week at the beginning of yr 5.  So if I don't get extra wk at yr 5, that means I am not eligigle for addition wk at yr 5, which I think that's in consistent with the policy.

Comment: @Riley - This answer was not really for you but for anyone visiting the site with this question after you.  Your company is saying no you do not get an extra week vacation.  What more do you want... If I tell you yes you still do not get the extra week.